# My map only updates on page refresh not on map refresh

Tags: javascript, google-maps

Hi the code below displays a map from coords taken from my database. when ever the GPS device moves the coords change in the database ok but when the map refreshes it doesn't show the new location it only updates when i refresh the page which is not great. looking at my code is there anything that stands out as to why this is?

```
        <script>
            google.maps.visualRefresh = true;

            var myCenter = new google.maps.LatLng(<?php echo $latlon; ?>);

            function initialize()
            {
                var mapProp = {
                    center: myCenter,
                    zoom: 17,
                    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                };

                var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"), mapProp);

                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: myCenter,
                    icon: 'images/bike.png'
                });

                marker.setMap(map);
            }

               var mapProp = setInterval(function () {
                navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(initialize);
            }, 15000);

            google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
        </script>

        <center><div id="googleMap" style="width:1000px;height:500px;"></div></center>
```

many thanks in advance.

Comment: `var myCenter = new google.maps.LatLng(<?php echo $latlon; ?>);` I guess your `myCenter` variable is always the same, as it was rendered once when page loaded. You can test this with `console.log(myCenter )` inside `initialize()`.Try to retrieve it from DB via web service every time you do `initialize()`.

Comment: thanks for your answers. 000webhost has just crashed so can't check anything. back soon I hope.

Comment: do you think people would down vote questions if everyone knew who the culprit was? stop hiding and speak up if you've got something clever to say.

Answer (score 1):

This won't update coordinates, if it was changed id DB:

```
var myCenter = new google.maps.LatLng(<?php echo $latlon; ?>);
```

But if you want to move marker following the user geolocation (browser-based), you should change you interval function to something like this:

```
var mapProp = setInterval(function () {
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (position) {
    myCenter = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);

    initialize();
  });
}, 1500);
```

Comment: Hi Keito, when the map refreshes your code just takes me back to my position and not the coords from the DB

Answer (score 0):

`navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition` accepts a success function in which the updated position is passed as an argument, like so:

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
    // you can now use position.latitude and position.longitude
    // to use the new position
});
```

Here’s a complete example that will update both the map as the marker:

```
// Store map and marker outside of initialize, so we can use it elsewhere
var map, marker;

function initialize() {
    var mapCenter = new google.maps.LatLng(<?php echo $latlon; ?>);

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"), {
        center: mapCenter,
        zoom: 17,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });

    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: mapCenter,
        icon: 'images/bike.png',
        map: map
    });

    // There’s no point in updating without having an active map,
    // so start the interval here
    setInterval(function() {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(updateCenter);
    }, 15000);
}

function updateCenter(position) {
    // The position getCurrentPosition passes, IS NOT a google.maps.LatLng object. First, we need to convert it:
    var mapCenter = new google.maps.LatLng(position.latitude, position.longitude);

    // Update stuff, instead of reinitializing
    marker.setPosition(mapCenter);
    map.setCenter(mapCenter);
}
```

Comment: Hi Tim thanks for your response, tried your code but the map does not show at all.